# Changing Variables with user inputs

Tags: java

Hey I am new to Java programing and I am wrestling with changing varibles and looking for a bit of help.  The question is below:

Create a program that asks the user for three numbers and then prints their sum. Use the following structure in your program:

```
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum = 0;
    int read;//`enter code here`
    // WRITE YOUR PROGRAM HERE
    // USE ONLY THE VARIABLES sum, reader AND read!
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
```

This is what I wrote below and of course I am getting syntax errors:

```
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum = 0;
    System.out.print("Type the first Number: ");
    int read = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    System.out.print("Type the second number: ");
    int read = read + (Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine()));
    System.out.print("Type the third number: ");
    int read = read + (Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine()));

    sum = read;
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
```

Comment: You should not be declaring your variables over and over again. `int read` is only required to create the variable. After that you can just use `read`. Also it's probably better to accumulate the result in sum instead of in read, that's it's purpose after all

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be something like:

```
   Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    int sum = 0;
    System.out.print("Type the first Number: ");
    int read = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    System.out.print("Type the second number: ");
    read = read + (Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine()));
    System.out.print("Type the third number: ");
    read = read + (Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine()));

    sum = read;
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
```

You are getting the syntax errors because your variable `read` is being declared multiple times.

You could also use the [compound assignment operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.26.2):

```
read += (Integer.parseInt(reader.nextInt())); //using .nextInt() per @Zong Zheng Li suggestion.
```

Comment: Maybe also use `reader.nextInt()` instead of `Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine())`.

Answer (score 0):

You declare the variable read over again, trying to declare the same variable again will give a syntax error.

```
int read = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
System.out.print("Type the second number: ");
read = read + (Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine()));
System.out.print("Type the third number: ");
read = read + (Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine()));
```

Answer (score 0):

package ejercicio.pkg25.cambio.de.variables.suma.de.tres.numeros;

/**
 * @author Diego Urrea
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio25CambioDeVariablesSumaDeTresNumeros {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum = 0;
    int read;
    System.out.println("Digita el primer número");
    read = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    sum = sum+read;
    System.out.println("Digita el segundo número");
    read = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    sum = sum+read;
    System.out.println("Digita el número tres");
    read = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    sum = sum+read;
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Actually for this short question, you **don't even** need to use `read` variable.

You could do it this way.

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum = 0;

System.out.print("Type the first Number: ");
sum += Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
System.out.print("Type the second number: ");
sum += Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
System.out.print("Type the third number: ");
sum += Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
```

**INPUT:**

```
1
2
3
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
6
```

Comment: @user2464795 **Remarks:** Your error is caused by creation of same variable within the same scope.